# R cannot be resolve with actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have added `actionbarsherlock`
And so far it is causing a headache. After solving many issues, I stuck with new issue.

WHen I derived my activity class from `SherlockFragment activity` and tried to use `R`, its giving me error `can not resolve symbol R`

**I have tried other solution on SO but could not resolve the issue**

I am unable to resolve this issue. My on create and activity class looks like this

```
    package pk.com.sd.absone;

 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;


 public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See htstps://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

}
```

}

Comment: Clean-Rebuild-Restart.

Comment: this is one solution already exist on SO and I already have tried

Comment: `I have added actionbarsherlock` ... **why**? It's no longer supported by the author. And you can use the [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) from the support library. There is really no reason to use ActionBarSherlock anymore.